# R: converting a complicated XML to dataframe

Tags: r, xml

I have an xml document which is a bit complicated, and I need help converting it to a dataframe. It looks like this (obviously the actual document is much larger):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImportFile xmlns="urn:ImportFile-schema">
  <HEADERVERSION>3.3</HEADERVERSION>
  <MESSAGETYPE>Import</MESSAGETYPE>
  <DESTINATIONORI>IL*****</DESTINATIONORI>
  <SOURCELAB>IL***** </SOURCELAB>
  <SUBMITBYUSERID>123456789</SUBMITBYUSERID>
  <SUBMITDATETIME>2020-07-12T18:31:00</SUBMITDATETIME>
  <SPECIMEN SOURCEID="Yes" CASEID="UNKNOWN" PARTIAL="false">
    <SPECIMENID>1234567</SPECIMENID>
    <SPECIMENCATEGORY>Known</SPECIMENCATEGORY>
    <SPECIMENCOMMENT>4</SPECIMENCOMMENT>
    <LOCUS BATCHID="EXPORT" PARTIALLOCUS="false" KIT="PowerPlex ESI 16">
      <LOCUSNAME>D16S539</LOCUSNAME>
      <READINGBY>Lab</READINGBY>
      <READINGDATETIME>2016-05-23T10:24:00</READINGDATETIME>
      <ALLELE>
        <ALLELEVALUE>9</ALLELEVALUE>
      </ALLELE>
      <ALLELE>
        <ALLELEVALUE>12.3</ALLELEVALUE>
      </ALLELE>
    </LOCUS>
    <LOCUS BATCHID="EXPORT" PARTIALLOCUS="false" KIT="PowerPlex ESI 16">
      <LOCUSNAME>D1S1656</LOCUSNAME>
      <READINGBY>Lab</READINGBY>
      <READINGDATETIME>2016-05-23T10:24:00</READINGDATETIME>
      <ALLELE>
        <ALLELEVALUE>12</ALLELEVALUE>
      </ALLELE>
      <ALLELE>
        <ALLELEVALUE>15</ALLELEVALUE>
      </ALLELE>
    </LOCUS>
  </SPECIMEN>
  <SPECIMEN SOURCEID="Yes" CASEID="UNKNOWN" PARTIAL="false">
    <SPECIMENID>9876543</SPECIMENID>
    <SPECIMENCATEGORY>Known</SPECIMENCATEGORY>
    <SPECIMENCOMMENT>4</SPECIMENCOMMENT>
    <LOCUS BATCHID="EXPORT" PARTIALLOCUS="false" KIT="PowerPlex ESI 16">
      <LOCUSNAME>D16S539</LOCUSNAME>
      <READINGBY>Lab</READINGBY>
      <READINGDATETIME>2016-03-17T08:50:00</READINGDATETIME>
      <ALLELE>
        <ALLELEVALUE>11</ALLELEVALUE>
      </ALLELE>
    </LOCUS>    
    <LOCUS BATCHID="EXPORT" PARTIALLOCUS="false" KIT="PowerPlex ESI 16">
      <LOCUSNAME>D1S1656</LOCUSNAME>
      <READINGBY>Lab</READINGBY>
      <READINGDATETIME>2016-03-17T08:50:00</READINGDATETIME>
      <ALLELE>
        <ALLELEVALUE>14</ALLELEVALUE>
      </ALLELE>
      <ALLELE>
        <ALLELEVALUE>17.3</ALLELEVALUE>
      </ALLELE>
    </LOCUS>
  </SPECIMEN>
</ImportFile>
```

What I want in the end is for each row in the dataframe to contain one SPECIMENID, and each column to contain one LOCUSNAME, as in the example:

```
SPECIMENID  D16S539  D1S1656 
1234567     9, 12.3  12, 15 
9876543     11       14, 17.3
```

I tried the following:

```
v<-xmlToDataFrame("filename.xml")
```

but got the error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c(SPECIMENID = "1234567",  : 
  duplicate subscripts for columns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlToDataFrame in particular doesn't seem to like duplicate nodes. Your best bet seems to be the package [xml2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html) and nested use the function [purrr::map](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map). I think for XPATH to work you also have to get rid of the namespace because no nodes are actually qualified by it:

```
library(tidyverse)
doc <- xml2::read_xml("filename.xml")
xml2::xml_ns_strip(doc)
specimen <- xml2::xml_find_all(doc, "SPECIMEN") %>% purrr::map_dfr(function(x) {
  specimenid <- xml2::xml_find_all(x, "./SPECIMENID") %>% xml2::xml_text()
  locus <- xml2::xml_find_all(x, "./LOCUS") %>% purrr::map_dfr(function(y) {
    locusname <- xml2::xml_find_all(y, "./LOCUSNAME") %>% xml2::xml_text()
    allele <- xml2::xml_find_all(y, "./ALLELE/ALLELEVALUE") %>% xml2::xml_text()
    dplyr::tibble(locusname, allele)
  })
  dplyr::tibble(specimenid, locus)
}) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from=locusname, values_from=allele)
```

I might not be able to explain it that well but basically, to be able to map ALLELEVALUEs to SPECIMENID and LOCUSNAME you want to nest data.frames so that ALLELEVALUEs are mapped to LOCUSNAME and that inner data.frame then is mapped to SPECIMENID. You can't do both at the same time/level I think. The pivot then brings the whole data.frame into the form you specified, the grouped ALLELEVALUEs can probably be unlisted.

Comment: This is a very elegant code and it works perfectly, thank you!